# Android HttpPost Returns <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> as Response

Tags: http-post

HttpPost Returns this response `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">` I have spent time trying to figure out why and I cant Know why. Someone help me please. sending data to a php site hosted at byethost. The funny thing is it works fine on a local server. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

### In Android

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8"))); 
request.setHeader("Content-type: application/json", json.toString());    
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

### In PHP

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
```